# infer exact value typescript

Tags: typescript

how do I make typescript infer the returned value from passed parameter

```
const toggle = <T, O extends [T,T]>(initialValue: T, options: O) => {
      return [initialValue, options];
    }

const [value, opts] = toggle("light", ["light", "dark"]);
```

the type of value is a `string`, I need it to be `"light" | "dark"`

Comment: If you can remove the dependency of this question on reactjs I might be able to advise; right now the `useState()` stuff is distracting (to me anyway) if this is just a TS type inference question.  For example [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WPZgJN) might be sufficient for you, but I can't tell right now

Comment: it is a type inference question, changed it a bit.

Comment: So does [this version](https://tsplay.dev/w8oXdW) work for you then?  If so, I can write up an answer. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: well, it does partially, In the initial example the idea of the function (hook) was to pass an initial value and an options tuple, the tuple must include the type of the initial value whatever it maybe

boolean -> [true, false]
string -> ['dark', 'light']
object -> [{name: "John"}, {name: "Amy"}]

and the returned value should infer the exact value(s) in the tuple

Comment: Can you add those additional use cases to your example code so that I can test against them?  (including the exact required output types for each input)

Comment: basically whatever values are passed to the options tuple, as example https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBFIHMEBsCmMC8MA8AVGqAHlKmACYQzQBOAlmAgDQwCqBxpFMuAfABT1aUWgENkANTEBXVAC5WzEAAdh4CPIDauZrgC6ASkw8YAbwCwAKBgxqqKFOpgYGwcLGTkMxStprdAbksAX0tLUEhYDQA3aVRvKAhdTDhEFFQ+EzARAFs5GAAiACtwfKDmDUycvKKSstMs3Pl8nIBPUoN-IA

Comment: And the exact output type?  I mean I can loosen the `string` requirement to a union of things that will cover most types like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wRR0Qw) but I don't know whether `{name: string}` is sufficient or you require `{name: "Jon"}` as the type (and how nested and crazy you need such "exact"-ness to be).

Comment: Note to myself or other interested parties: feels like https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30680 to me

Comment: the output type is `{name: "Jon"} | {name: "Amy"}`
I am new to typesctipt, and I get the feeling that this does not have a simple "elegant" solution

And it does feel like the issue you mentioned

Comment: So then maybe [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WoGYgW)?

Comment: yes! that works just fine)

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get the chance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conceptually, your `toggle()` function could be typed as simply as:

```
const toggle = <T, U>(initialValue: T | U, options: readonly [T, U]) => {
  return [initialValue, options] as const;
}
```

Here the two [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters `T` and `U` correspond to the first and second members of the `options` [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) (marked as a [`readonly` tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-tuple-types) which is actually *less* restrictive than a normal read-write tuple).  And the type of `initialValue` is the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of `T` and `U`.

This will catch major errors in your input types:

```
toggle(3, ["abc", true]); // error!
// --> ~ Argument of type '3' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | boolean'.
// toggle<string, boolean>(...)
```

Here `T` was inferred as `string`, and `U` was inferred as `boolean`, and the input `3` does not match `string | boolean`.

But unfortunately due to the way type inference works in TypeScript, it will not detect the following as an error:

```
toggle("oops", ["light", "dark"]); // no error
// toggle<string, string>(...)
```

After all, `T` is `string` and `U` is `string`, and `"oops"` is also a `string`.  But you wanted the compiler to treat `"light"`, `"dark"`, and `"oops"`, as string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), so that `"light"` is of type `"light"`, which is not compatible with `"oops"`.

---

The TypeScript compiler uses heuristics to infer the type of a value.  When it sees  the value `{name: "jon"}`, it tends to infer `{name: string}`, assuming that `"jon"` is just an initializer for a property which may take any `string` value.  That's often what people want. But sometimes it's not.  Sometimes people want the entire value to be treated as *immutable* as possible, and therefore the type should be as *specific* as possible.

In these cases you can use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to tell the compiler this:

```
let v = "light"; // string
let w = "light" as const; // "light"
let x = { name: 'jon' }; // { name: string }
let y = { name: 'jon' } as const; //  { readonly name: "jon" }
```

If we use `const` assertions on both inputs when calling `toggle()`, things will suddenly work how you want:

```
toggle("oops" as const, ["light", "dark"] as const); // error!
// --> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
// Argument of type '"oops"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"light" | "dark"

const [v1, o1] = toggle("light" as const, ["light", "dark"] as const);
// v1: "light" | "dark"
const [v2, o2] = toggle({ a: 456 } as const, [{ a: 456 }, { b: 789 }] as const)
// v2: { readonly a: 456 } | { readonly b: 789 }
const [v3, o3] = toggle(true as const, [true, false] as const);
// v3: boolean
const [v4, o4] = toggle({ name: "jon" } as const, [{ name: "jon" }, { name: "amy" }] as const);
// v4: { readonly name: "jon" } | { readonly name: "amy" }
```

So that's great, but it relies on the *caller* of `toggle()` using a `const` assertion.

---

It would be nice if you could *implement* `toggle()` in such a way that the generic inference for the `T` and `U` type parameters could be "`const`-asserted", so that the caller does not have to write `as const` if they pass literals into `toggle()`.

Unfortunately, there's no simple way to do this.  A while back I filed [microsoft/TypeScript#30680](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30680) requesting support for this, but it's not clear when or if this will be implemented.

For now, there are tricks you can use to get similar behavior, but they are not pretty.  If you have a generic type parameter `X extends string`, it will tend to infer a string literal type for `X`.  And `X extends number` will do the same for numeric literals.  So `X extends string | number | boolean` will infer string literals, numeric literals, and boolean literals.  But if you want these to be inferred at a nested levels, you need something like `X extends string | number | boolean | {[k: string]: X}`.  And if you want to infer tuple types instead of unordered arrays, you need to have some tuple types in your domain of inference also, so maybe `X extends string | number | boolean | [] | {[k: string]: X}`.  And you don't want to prohibit other types, so you need to include other stuff in there like `null` and `object`.  Ideally you'd want to include [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type) because it allows everything, but that would throw away all the hinting.  So you need to define a `Narrowable` type that is *like* `unknown` except it can be used to narrow to literals.

That gives you this:

```
type Narrowable = string | number | boolean | symbol | bigint
  | null | undefined | object | {} | [] | void;

const toggle = <
  T extends Narrowable | { [k: string]: T },
  U extends Narrowable | { [k: string]: U }
>(initialValue: T | U, options: [T, U]) => {
  return [initialValue, options] as const;
}
```

Let's see if it works:

```
toggle("oops", ["light", "dark"]); // error

const [v1, o1] = toggle("light", ["light", "dark"]);
// v1: "light" | "dark"

const [v2, o2] = toggle({ a: 456 }, [{ a: 456 }, { b: 789 }])
// v2: { a: 456 } | { b: 789 }

const [v3, o3] = toggle(true, [true, false]);
// v3: boolean

const [v4, o4] = toggle({ name: "jon" }, [{ name: "jon" }, { name: "amy" }]);
// v4: { name: "jon" } | { name: "amy" }
```

Looks good.  It behaves much like the original version when you use `as const`, except that it's not inferring `readonly` properties for objects... which you didn't really care about to begin with, probably.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/LAKAdghgtgpgzgBwgYxgAgFLIgGwF5oDeooaaOMALmgG5oC8aARDgJYDmAFpUwNxoB6AWjiUATqzDtS5KmgDuDZmy480EOGmQB7MKP5DlHbkxkVqADyWE0kWAC40AcgBWup2gC+B4TbsxHUQkpLzM5AE9rW2gA5zcwD091TR09Sh8yGzEYCAATXRxI-0cmeKZQkBl-RBR0AGFdUQBBODgYMWpiEDIyVNE0Sm12dgolAB4AFQAaNABVAD4ACklWSlZcADVcAFdYibQAHzmZ7QQ1xsdsvILIgG1puYBdAEoGeaIZHrRsym2xMDQtxWa02OxgJzOrEaj2SWka6U+FURg2GFEWAGYZrcmBAAEbIJgzcS7F4ZdpibRiACEiMMAFo6e8AH5oJpidjbWBgajaABmA3CCHQTnRHlYmjA2moGjgHEguNGgzQSDEMUo7TQfIFQucQUk7EOaFx2m0FAgCQAdLThCiRjAxnqpDNjaacmAlhbPc8SN0era0UwTQg4ITASxjDwZkxchAxABrJikwTCSVocmUn1ff0wRaB04h2F9ShY8OqUPR2MJmEaOFpZ5ksQU6nWtAM5lMjudrtdtAttkcrk8-mUQXCvPBphiiVS5Ky9jyxXaZWxtUarUjnVOUsmQ0V+OmSq+3rwwE0ACMJzPMMY2dzKh3NaLJfvkeYMf31ZS8PrLfPJRf5RHHuCaIkWp4AEwnOB14DEMdqLDYECOAALAArAAbF4hbwliiEoRhXgzDYuKOAA7AAHAAnF4n61qI3pHsmtDgY4WQ5PkYCFOo+GYUkRxsdcnGRCRaAUdRnigSetw0JimrojBt7Eugj44YCSkzLyuBtLRRY-oxhgyY4LpmmAklpKeyEnMhClwWifgxCUZRYSpaS4dEDjME5nhEe5sQ4lA4TlJ4Onfrwv7Iax3zsTcvmOboQWGgJHFccUzDQIFSK+hJh5kNUSCoGgACSYC8u0EwSMgcaaF0yKjmgABysYUvIeKjIwjoGkcYCcriGpHMZbqGnA4RQMaOCGriHCSJQiJkF12w4ONRzbGAuQwLykgwLkhraLiLgwMg1D8XxgIwkcNDaKwuRhTlPRgdm4yzWg+wwBY6qrZojWNtoLUKug-GAnGgTiPqjyOPs3lPbMaZvTAH0NU1P2tf9RCA8DwTsGDcwVF8SzAusOBbDguzg4aswQuceiOPcMyzC8bwfIxZA-H8AJAmAqwE0TuwU1CeghWkN1fNlmZ+rZObjiGz4RuW75VvWTHpmIovHuZ0kXpqV5KLe26vtiAFRnLiZ6V8Blnv+Mu7kbKt0dQ0mQZq0Ha+LCHcWgaG8W5SHuwR3moyJYk0QxpvCDQLGo97HtYQDAdUZlXxgdJsnaPJzuojm6lqWIPNoJpODaSbPQGeiRkmiZNuJzQlmatZafwfZHmlPFhGAg3fleT5qX+RlwWF2QBkRajXdeYlsVpQFQWIjI2WeEAA)