# Is it possible to get the index of an array item when creating a type in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a function `createCells`  that takes an array of strings and returns an object whose properties depends on the index of items in the array

For example the function  `createCells(['10', '12', '13'])`  would return an object with properties `{Cell0, Cell1, Cell2}`

So far I've been able to create one where the object returned is based on the value of items in the array

```
const createCells = <T extends `${number}`[]>(
    args: T,
) => {
    return args.reduce(
        (prev, curr) => ({
            ...prev,
            [`Cell${curr}`]: () => { },
        }),
        {}
    ) as {
            [key in typeof args[number] as `Cell${key}`]: (
            ) => void;
        };
};
```

but this way the function  `createCells(['10', '12', '13'])`  would return  an object with  properties `{Cell10, Cell12, Cell13}`

For what I'm trying to achieve, the function would be

```
const createCells = <T extends `${number}`[]>(
    args: T,
) => {
    return args.reduce(
        (prev, curr, index) => ({
            ...prev,
            [`Cell${index}`]: () => { },
        }),
        {}
    ) 
};
```

How do i use typescript to indicate the type of the object returned by the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// it is possible to get the length of a tuple and therefore you can create a counter
type Increment<T extends unknown[]> = [...T, unknown]

// create a helper type to do something based on the value and the index
type CellType<CellValue, Index extends unknown[]> = { [K in `Cell${Index["length"]}`]: CellValue } // do something based on the value or the index

// Iterate over your tuple and intersect the result of CellType<~,~> to create the target object
type CreateCells<T extends unknown[], Index extends unknown[] = []> =
    T extends [infer Head, ...infer Rest]
    ? CellType<Head, Index> & CreateCells<Rest, Increment<Index>>
    : {}
```

[infer exact value typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71889103/infer-exact-value-typescript)

```
// This type gets infers the value without using required and
// prettifies the intersection {a:"a"} & {b:"b"} => {a:"a",b:"b"}
export type Narrowable = string | number | bigint | boolean;
export type Narrow<A> =
    | (A extends Narrowable ? A : never)
    | (A extends [] ? [] : never)
    | {
        [K in keyof A]: A[K] extends Function ? A[K] : Narrow<A[K]>;
    };
```

```
const createCells = <T extends `${number}`[]>(
    // Narrow allows us prevent the widening
    args: Narrow<T>,
): Narrow<CreateCells<T>> => {
    // for narrow we have to cast the argument 
    return (args as unknown as string[]).reduce(
        (prev, curr, index) => ({
            ...prev,
            [`Cell${index}`]: () => { },
        }),
        // yeah, any here to make our ts-compiler happy
        // I think this is a common practice if you are creating an object dynamicly
        {} as any
    )
};

type Test = Narrow<CreateCells<["1", "3"]>>

const x = createCells(["1", "2", "3", "124214"]) //{ Cell0: "1"; Cell1: "2"; Cell2: "3"; Cell3: "124214";}
const z = createCells(["1", "2", "3", "124214asd"]) //invalid
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false&target=99&noFallthroughCasesInSwitch=true&allowUmdGlobalAccess=true&pretty=true&ts=4.8.0-beta#code/LAKA9GAECWAuMGdIAcD2CHQEYBsCmksqkA5nvLABYH4B2JVkqAZpAIaECuy+7tAJoWoAnPM1SjIAT1SdIAYza0FotrAId5s2uuGhYU5AQCSteaIC2eHQB4AKpDwAPdQKSdaAa1qoA7rQBtAF0APkgAXkgAgDpYuwAaSA9vP1og0FAIFTw1DUhqHCNhQkMCIkh+YgRUKypoekgsNgQ8QVRlKgIANzYcTg0BIQJ6-md9UsgAYTwcHDtSm2nZgDVe-sTTUadHF2t+dy8ff2CwyIBvKIBpGGUAAyWcABIzzecAgCI6Bkp3oIBfW5BABcUxmOFWfQIf0gWUqkGqtUo9RIjWarSYHWokB6kKYxU6Ny2GXAUGMulyTC6eGKMk4+O4vCUgnquha8goWNECE4OHgLFBs3mRhsAD94iKwuVzDl1ENCGxhGQ+VgAFZ4dnjIxTVTqB4Iew7Vz7JKHVLBDYCZyGvYHFLHIIRKKhCKgSBuyAOZxGpABerMamQAASOX4iVi0T9AYASngELB0iB3ZAAPwCuYLYNsUOQV5OMIAMm1MrwepsMbjFulVlsuZCIVd7pBZz+xKylFgsGQCCBEDjbHknlQVOEzBwfmiWgsYAAjv049B2ggwAB2ACMAA51wBOVcABgAzGBI8IALTOfuwE84-ongxGBDmaDIWCZKB2JFIO8EJVIY+frHXgQvhwJQsjwJwmANKIs7QKIghMq+KCiB20DMNAsZyiy1JsrAC7KGcbBAu8bDvNChZnFgRFYKRERhARREkfElHvNRLYgM4aDCBQEwAHIKsIfhsLgBCRHGwjIpAAA+kC0JwFhYAG0lYNAJAslJjSoKg+BKAA3KAHESNxWp8cIAm+DYACCpwNm60kABQWdabiQCZZlCbwqaOSCtB4MOACUNnqQ5TnGsEKZOpA3m+dSAWJu60lnIFSYBNc9SQJ4eAyKwFnApAFkpQ6Xo2pAABiHjsnh4X5ZcDogq5fiWQVIR6XFbp-C1xJaLQcbZLkeqOgaRXObczyyfJ1IAicdmBVk9W+Owsx+O4SDIKIVI6HKwGjLQyKBQqJDdi5-ENXYITxKAfl1cd5mTDqJZgvqp2nHRM1QOIxS0NdkC+AQlBsFShDEIoPUEvtcnWPAgXIXSyh2ftSDNCadrKIjYnIsEfnRHBnDyHg02tUmkB2atvmJPIdLCIkIzOH5tFE4lBOE+64Yk1052M0zUT3GCzzU04AK5XZtPhHRkB-OznNi35Euc1kUg5JQiRKFI+TUmUxAWGwGVMHShAICek7INA+DFH9yDIFISXulkxhCPUnh27+CMKDUFjtEhF7QLjMCsLS7CSNKagSUoTCquq8D8FIn0WF7OCWxzbrNuwCO0PHSaxe1xJfh6sbwJEc2LHdpYfKu7yJO8+6-HWnWLvA2yRIHuoPXZJdl5A7wAExtxX3erh3AAsHerv3vy0xAFwPLuILvKXOlpqu09d3PDwd9PlfL2C+7T33g-D+8OlsV1PUAF6Oo392zAgLcz93Xfl5X5c70P-fNPwo8wketA4tA-DEkAA)

Comment: Thank you so much. Would probably need to spend some days with this code snippet to really understand it. Thanks again